# ANTLR4 Grammar doesn't recognize Boolean literals

Tags: antlr4

Why won't the below grammar recognize boolean values?

I've compared this to the grammars for both Java and GraphQL, and cannot see why it doesn't work.

Given the below grammar, parses is as follows:

```
foo = null // foo = value:nullValue
foo = 123 // foo = value:numberValue
foo = "Hello" // foo = value:stringValue
foo = true // line 1:6 mismatched input 'true' expecting {'null', STRING, BOOLEAN, NUMBER}
```

What is wrong?

```
grammar issue;

elementValuePair
    :   Identifier '=' value
    ;

Identifier : [_A-Za-z] [_0-9A-Za-z]* ;

value
   : STRING # stringValue | NUMBER # numberValue | BOOLEAN # booleanValue | 'null' #nullValue
   ;

STRING
   : '"' ( ESC | ~ ["\\] )* '"'
   ;

BOOLEAN
   : 'true' | 'false'
   ;

NUMBER
   : '-'? INT '.' [0-9]+| '-'? INT | '-'? INT
   ;

fragment INT
   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*
   ;

fragment ESC
   : '\\' ( ["\\/bfnrt]  )
   ;

fragment HEX
   : [0-9a-fA-F]
   ;

WS
   : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip
   ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because the token 'true' matches lexer rule Identifier:

```
[@0,0:2='foo',<Identifier>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='=',<'='>,1:4]
[@2,6:9='true',<Identifier>,1:6] <== lexed as an Identifier!
[@3,14:13='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
line 1:6 mismatched input 'true' expecting {'null', STRING, BOOLEAN, NUMBER}
```

Move your definition of Identifier down farther to be among the lexer rules and it works:

```
NUMBER
   : '-'? INT '.' [0-9]+| '-'? INT | '-'? INT
   ;

Identifier : [_A-Za-z] [_0-9A-Za-z]* ;
```

Remember stuff at the top trumps stuff at the bottom.  In a combined grammar like yours, don't intersperse the lexer rules (which start with a capital letter) with parser rules (which start with a lowercase letter).

Comment: Keep in mind that first the lexer tries the longest match. If `BOOLEAN` would match more input than anything the `Identifier` rule can match then `BOOLEAN` would be choosen by the lexer. For instance you could use a predicate to limit the number of chars matched by `Identifier` (would be 3, for `false` and `true`), then the grammar would match these keyowrds as is.

Comment: Thanks @MikeLischke and true enough.  However, the OP's unorthodox mixing of a lexer rule as literally the second rule in the grammar was the root cause of the problem he described.  I've been similarly stumped before and simply running TestRig in -tokens mode gave me that "a-ha!" moment.

Comment: Yes indeed, a very common problem.